# Javascripts to enable custom action button on multiple selected SharePoint List Items

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am setting up a new sharepoint list on team site and want to create a custom action button to trigger workflow on selected list items.

I Created the custom action button and added scripts in web part. However, the custom action button is still not available if more than 1 items are selected.

I expect the custom action button to be enabled when multiple items are selected.

Answer (score 0):

To work with multiple items when choosing, use [SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff409526(v%3Doffice.14)), look at this [example](https://mickdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/08/ribbons-customization-in-sharepoint.html).

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
```

and use EnableScript to *Elements.xml*:

```
EnabledScript="var EnableDisableItem = function()
{
this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
this.selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(this.clientContext);
if (selectedItems.length==1)  {
if (selectedItems[0].fsObjType == 0)
{return true;}
else
{return false;}
}
if (selectedItems.length!=1)
{return false;}
};
EnableDisableItem();"
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this apply to all custom action buttons? I read many posts and some are using commandhandler to refer to the specific custom action button.